# Pandas Timeseries: Keep only one value peer week and id

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

**Problem**

I have a mysql database that saves a time series (for each customer and a date the balance of the customer's account). Each week might have multiple values. The date column can be assumed a valid and complete datetime object. There might be multiple entries per customer and week, but I want to keep only one value a week.
I query the database and construct a corresponding pandas dataframe from it.

Constraints:

- Most constantly there will be values on a tuesday of each week
- Sometimes the tuesday might not have a value, take the next possible value in that week then

```
+-------------+------------+---------+
| customer_id |    date    | balance |
+-------------+------------+---------+
|          01 | 01.01.2020 | 50$     |
|          02 | 01.01.2020 | 40$     |
|          01 | 02.01.2020 | 40$     |
|          01 | 08.01.2020 | 60$     |
+-------------+------------+---------+
```

**Solution**

A solution contains:

- one value for each customer each week (no duplicate values peer week / day)
- the value is the earliest possible value

From the example this would like this:

```
+-------------+------------+---------+
| customer_id |    date    | balance |
+-------------+------------+---------+
|          01 | 01.01.2020 | 50$     |  
|          02 | 01.01.2020 | 40$     |
|          01 | 08.01.2020 | 60$     | 
+-------------+------------+---------+
```

**How it could be solved / Question**

I could iterate the dataframe and for every id and week select the first value within a week and save it to a new df / delete all other entries.
This seems rather inefficent. Is there a solution that is more tailored to pandas or maybe that I could even improve the mysql query to filter out the data as needed already?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change `date` to period, and groupby:

```
df.groupby([df.date.dt.to_period('W-TUE'), 
            df['customer_id']]).head(1)
```

Output:

```
  customer_id       date  balance
0          01 2020-01-01       50
1          02 2020-01-01       40
3          01 2020-01-08       60
```

Comment: 'W-TUE' means weekly Tuesdays, does that mean, that it selects only values each Tuesday? What if there are two values on a given Tuesday for a customer and what if there's only a value on a Wednesday? Would those cases be covered?

Comment: That means your weeks start from Tuesdays. Pandas default is week starting from Mondays.

Comment: Ok, i just checked that on the data and it works which is very cool.
I assume the head selects the first value for every group, correct? Why does it not return only the head of the complete dataframe (so only one row total).

Comment: One more important question: Could there be a case where this would lead to aggregating the balance?
Say, I have to entries on the same date for a customer (50, 50), could I end up with 100 for that date?

Comment: replace `head(1)` with `sum()` and you would get the weekly sum.